# Why not to use ViewBag heavily?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

What if i use too many ViewBag in MVC3 page? What extreme problems will be there if i continue use them heavily. In less words, what are the disadvantages of ViewBag and what is the alternate for it?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779294/viewmodels-or-viewbag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> what is the alternate for it?

You should only use [**ViewModels**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx), It's the recommended approach. Create Strongly typed views. It would make your code cleaner and easy to maintain.

> What extreme problems will be there?

Issue with Viewbags/ViewData is compile time checking. ViewBags are just dictionaries and you won't be aware about any issues until run time and thus it makes your code error-prone. So always try to go with ViewModels.

Comment: what if use them heavily ?

Answer (score 5):

Two points I know:

1. It makes your controllers less testable.
2. Your views are not strongly typed

Answer (score -2):

It has the possibility to hit performance at run-time.