# MVC Core Trying to fill a table row by selecting first column

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm very new to programming and I got really confused how to do this..

What I'm trying to do is a table for creating an offer after picking the materials I want. Price will change while I pick different materials. At the end, I will save the offer, with total price etc.

I have a list of Product Models. And in my view, I would like to pick the product model I want in "First Column" using it's FullName and I want to populate other columns in same row with the Models' predefined details that I just picked.

I made a research how to do it. Jquery, Ajax were mentioned but I will have to add more of those dropdown lists with more Viewbags. Don't I have to write a new Ajax for each dropdown then?

I really hope to be guided in what way I should try to do this.

```
public class Model:BaseEntity
{
    public TypeOfPart TypeOfPart { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public string VersionName { get; set; }
    public decimal? ListPriceTL { get; set; }
    public decimal? ListPriceForeign { get; set; }
    public ForeignCurrency? ForeignCurrency { get; set; }
    public decimal CurrentDiscount { get; set; } = 0.00M;

    public int? CertificateId { get; set; }
    public Certificate Certificate { get; set; }

    public string FullName => $"{BrandName} {ModelName} {VersionName}";
```

My Controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        int amountOfElevators = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Amount"]);
        ViewBag.amount = amountOfElevators;


        ViewData["Machines"] = new SelectList(_context.ModelRepo.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.TypeOfPart 
==TypeOfPart.Machine),"Id","FullName");
        
   

        ViewData["ConstructionCompanyId"] = new 
SelectList(_context.ConstructionCompanyRepo.GetAll(), "Id", "Name","Id");
        ViewData["EmployeeId"] = new 
SelectList(_context.EmployeeRepo.GetAll(), "Id", "FullName");
        return View();
    }
```

[Here's the image for a little more description of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWhuL.jpg)

EDIT:
My View Model

```
public class InstallationOfferVM
{
    public InstallationOfferVM()
    {
        OfferedElevators = new List<OfferedElevator>();
        Models = new List<Model>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Toplam ₺")]
    public decimal TotalPriceTL { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Toplam €")]
    public decimal TotalPriceEuro { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Açıklama")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Müşteri Firma")]
    public int ConstructionCompanyId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Müşteri Firma")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public ConstructionCompany ConstructionCompany { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Teklif Tarihi")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateOfProposal { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Teklifi Veren")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Teklifi Veren")]
    public string EmployeeFullName { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Teklif Durumu")]
    public ProposalStatus ProposalStatus { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "İletme Şekli")]
    public DeliveredBy DeliveredBy { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Asansör Adedi")]
    public int AmountOfElevators { get; set; }


    public List<OfferedElevator> OfferedElevators { get; set; }
    public OfferedElevator OfferedElevator { get; set; }


    public int InstallationOfferId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Kapasite")]
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Durak")]
    public int StopCount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Halat Adedi")]
    public int MachineRopeCount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Askı Tipi")]
    public int HangStyle { get; set; } = 1;
    [Display(Name = "Tahrik Tipi")]
    public DriveType DriveType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Ortalama Kat Yüksekliği")]
    public decimal AvgFloorHeight { get; set; } = 3.00M;
    [Display(Name = "Giriş Adedi")]
    public int EntranceCount { get; set; } = 1;
    [Display(Name = "Ekstra Kapı")]
    public int AdditionalDoor { get; set; } = 1;
    [Display(Name = "Ağırlık Yanda İse")]
    public bool WeightInSide { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Kapı Yüksekliği 2100 ise")]
    public bool DoorHeightIs2100 { get; set; } = false;
    [Display(Name = "Euro Kuru")]
    public decimal CurrentEuro { get; set; }
    public List<Model> Models { get; set; }
    public Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

My View

```
@model Ace.ViewModels.InstallationOfferVM
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.amount; i++)
{
<table class="table-sm table-striped table-dark col-md-9">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Malzeme Cinsi</th>
                    <th>Adet</th>
                    <th>Liste Euro</th>
                    <th>Liste TL</th>
                    <th>İskonto</th>
                    <th>Toplam</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><select asp-for="Model.Id" class="form-control" asp- 
items="ViewBag.Machines"></select></td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr />
}
</form>
<div>
<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: do not use Viewdata to pass model to view. you can pass model to view. some limiation of viewdata is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567891/why-not-to-use-viewbag-heavily.

Comment: Could you demonstrate your View (.cshtml) file?

Comment: I've noticed that I shouldn't use Viewdata to pass model to view. But I'm quite unsure how to achieve my goal so I was trying everything :)

Comment: To pass the viewmodel to your view, just do return View(viewmodel);

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change your controller method this way:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var offeredElevators = //query here to get the offeredElevators
    var viewmodel = new InstallationOfferVM 
    {
       OfferedElevators = offeredElevators,
       Models = new List<Model>()
    };

    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

this way you can at least get your data to the view, how it is supposed to be done. I am not sure if i agree with your model/viewmodel though..

hope this helps a little at least