# Can't display form input in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have simple view in ASP.NET 4:

```
<form action="GetWeather" method="post">
    <input name="city" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<h1>@ViewBag.City</h1>
```

And simple controller which was supposed to display input from the form on the same page:

```
public class WeatherController : Controller
{
    string cityName = "TBD";
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.City = cityName;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetWeather(string city)
    {
        cityName = city;
        return Redirect("/Weather/Index");
    }
}
```

After submit I keep getting my `"TBD"` string. I couldn't find anything about it, as everything is based on model, which I don't need.

Comment: You are not setting ViewBag.City in the action that handles POST. When you debug GetWeather is `city` correct based on the form input?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes, while debugging, cityName sets to string passed in argument, after redirecting to Index, it is "TBD" again

Comment: That is because every request instantiates a new WeatherController and you are setting it to "TBD". I encourage you to pass viewmodels to views instead of relying on viewbag.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it is instantiated per session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use  strongly typed view instead of using the `ViewBag`. It would make your code cleaner and easy to maintain.

```cs
public class WeatherController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string city = "TBD")
    {
        return View((object)city);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetWeather(string city)
    {            
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { city });
    }
}
```

```
@model string

@using (Html.BeginForm("GetWeather", "Weather", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input name="city" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
}

<h1>@Model</h1>
```

[Why not to use ViewBag heavily?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15568190/6630084)

[ViewBag vs Model, in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21716953/6630084)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GetWeather(string city)
{
    cityName = city;
    return Index();
}
```