# How do I show the results of information from my database to my view using viewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Here is my controller:

```cs
[HttpGet("")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
   ViewBag.showMonster =  _context.Monsters.ToList();
            
    return View();
}
```

and here is my `cshtml`:

```
<h1>@ViewBag.showMonster</h1>
```

Is this the wrong syntax?
My view is showing:

> System.Collections.Generic.List1[PracticeEntity.Models.Monster]

instead of the the actual row from my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use  strongly typed view instead of using the `ViewBag`. It would make your code cleaner and easy to maintain.

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_context.Monsters.ToList());
}
```

In the view:

```
@model IList<Monster>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => item) <br />
}
```

[Why not to use ViewBag heavily?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15568190/6630084)

[ViewBag vs Model, in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21716953/6630084)

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach to loop the object list item in the view.

```
 @foreach(var item in ViewBag.showMonster )
  {            
      <tr>    
        <td>@item.Name</td>
      </tr>        
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Just curious, why didn't what I had work? do I have to do a loop anytime I want to show something?

Comment: If you have a collection, array, or list.  You will need a loop.  The program will not able to guess how you want the list item to be display.

Answer (score 0):

Just traverse the List data in your database and take it out. I wrote some data:

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Test> test = new List<Test>()
            {
                new Test{id=1,name="test1"},
                  new Test{id=2,name="test2"},
                    new Test{id=3,name="test3"},

            };
            return View(test);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IList<WebApplication69.Models.Test>

@foreach(var item in Model)
            {
<div> @item.name</div>
            }
```

Result:

[image]