# Subtracting Two ViewBag Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Not sure if this is the right way to go about this.  But, I have two textboxes on a view that are populated by Viewbag from the controller.  They are int values.  One Value is the Number of units in stock (`Viewbag.stock`)  and the other is the number of units ordered (`Viewbag.ordered`).  I have a third textbox that I want to show the value of `Viewbag.Stock - Viewbag.Ordered`.

I tried doing this in the controller, but that didn't bring back a result.  I also tried doing this in the value of the textbox, and that also did not work.

This is the first way that I tried to accomplish this

Model

```
        public int? OnHand { get; set; }
        public int? UnitsOrdered { get; set; }
```

controller

```
        ViewBag.Stock = r.FirstOrDefault().OnHand;
        ViewBag.Ordered = r.FirstOrDefault().UnitsOrdered;
        ViewBag.Total = ViewBag.Stock - ViewBag.Ordered;
```

View

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnitsOrdered, (string)"Units On Hand ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">              
            @Html.TextBox("OnHand", null, new { @class = "form-control", Value = ViewBag.Stock, @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnitsOrdered, (string)"Number of Units Ordered", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UnitsOrdered, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @ViewBag.MyCountIntro @ViewBag.MyCount
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UnitsOrdered, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>

            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox("Remaining", null, new { @class = "form-control", Value = ViewBag.Total, @readonly = "readonly" })
            </div>
```

In the above scenario, Viewbag.Stock is 60.  Viewbag.Ordered is 2. Viewbag.Total should be 58.  But instead, it is blank

I have also tried to calculate this in the view, itself.  Which also yields a blank.

```
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox("Remaining", null, new { @class = "form-control", Value = ViewBag.Stock - Viewbag.Ordered, @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewBag itself will treat the value as an object. You should cast that object to appropriate type before doing your calculation.

`ViewBag.Total = (int)ViewBag.Stock - (int)ViewBag.Ordered;`

Comment: Thank you @Adriani6. This is the solution that I used.  Although both solutions were great . . . and the other one was maybe a bit more proper.  Your solution was easy to understand and the best to resolve the problem, in the manner that I had started.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could add a view model instead of using the ViewBag (see [ViewModels or ViewBag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779294/viewmodels-or-viewbag)):

```
class MyViewModel { 
    public int Ordered {get; set;}
    public int Stock {get; set;}
    public int Total => Stock - Ordered;
}
```

This will be a much more maintainable code since it'll allow easy refactoring, typed member and so on.