# Foreign Key not showing in dropdown box | MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm somewhat new to MVC and have been following along with a tutorial but it has no answers regarding my question. For my `Create` page, the Foreign keys are not showing up. Basically, on the Projects page I created a project, on the People page I created a person. So when I try to create a `ProjectRole` on the `ProjectRoles` page, the `ProjectId` and `PersonId` are not showing up in the drop-down menu. Down below all of my code, I have provided a screenshot of what I have tried to put into words.

My models:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProjectRole> ProjectRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProjectRole> ProjectRoles { get; set; }
}
public class ProjectRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double HourlyRate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Project")]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AppRole")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

}
```

My Controller code:

```cs
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,HourlyRate,PersonId,ProjectId,RoleId")] ProjectRole projectRole)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(projectRole);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(projectRole);
}
```

And my view code here:

```
@model Project2.Models.Entities.ProjectRole

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>ProjectRole</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="HourlyRate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="HourlyRate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="HourlyRate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PersonId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="PersonId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PersonId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ProjectId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProjectId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RoleId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="RoleId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="RoleId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Screenshot of example of what I mean:

[image: Screenshot of example of what I mean]

Comment: If you are using ViewBag.PersonId for filling your PersonId dropdown and same as ProjectId. So in your controller code, there is no code for filling this viewbag value. I think you missed some code from the tutorial or something else. Please recheck your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose more personable to display the *Person Name* (and the *Project Name*) in the select controls, but to pass the `PersonId` (and `ProjectId`) to the Create method when click on the <kbd>Create</kbd> button.

Therefore, prepare the `Person` list (and the `Project` list) like below:

```cs
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var persons = new List<SelectListItem>();
    // Iterate through `Persons`
    foreach(var p in _context.Persons)
    {
        persons.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value= p.Id, Text = p.FirstName+", "+p.LastName}); 
    }  
    ViewBag.Persons = persons; 

    // Prepare the projects list (like `Persons` list above)
    // ... your code here
    ViewBag.Projects = persons; 

    return View(new ProjectRole(){ /* Add your code here to create the ProjectRole .../* });
}
```

And in the view:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="PersonId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="PersonId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Persons"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ProjectId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="ProjectId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Projects"></select>
</div>
```

For additional information see [The Select Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-select-tag-helper)

*NOTE: And I would recommend to create compound view model to include all required information. *

- [ViewModels or ViewBag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13779294/6630084)
- [Understanding Best Way to Use Multiple Models in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/understanding-best-way-to-use-multiple-models-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: In the Create method, what did you mean by both instances of "your code here"? Is it code that I have already created in my example or something new? I am still a bit confused. Thanks!

Comment: Your `Create()` action method does not contain any code to populate your view model. But the view contain the view model declaration: `@model Project2.Models.Entities.ProjectRole`. Therefore, I added the remark, that you should add some code to populate your view model and pass it to the view by `View(model);`. OK, I have moved the code for better clarity.

Comment: Got it, thank you!